# Как отключить звук или полностью выключить мелодию JS

Tags: javascript

Есть `html` код

```
<h4 id="fun" onclick="soundStart()">Включение мелодии</h4>
<h4 id="sad" onclick="soundStop()">Выключение мелодии</h4>
```

и `js` скрипт к нему

```
function soundStart() {
      let audio = new Audio(); // Создание элемента аудие
      audio.src = 'Мелодия.mp3'; // путь к самой мелодии
      audio.autoplay = true; //Автозапуск
      audio.volume = 0.001; //Громкость
      let fun = document.getElementById("fun").style.display = "none"; // Скрытие текста, который запускает мелодию
      let sad = document.getElementById("sad").style.display = "block";// показ текста, который её остановит
    function soundStop(){
        audio.volume = 0;
    }
}
```

Собственно ничего не происходит, звук как был так и остаётся, а как полностью остановить мелодию я не придумал.
Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = 'https://zvukipro.com/uploads/files/2021-09/1630518601_olympic-hymn-immortal-spirit-of-antiquity.mp3'; // путь к самой мелодии
audio.volume = 1; //Громкость
let fun = document.getElementById("fun");
let sad = document.getElementById("sad");
sad.style.display = "none";

function soundStart() {
  audio.play();
  fun.style.display = "none"; // Скрытие текста, который запускает мелодию
  sad.style.display = "block"; // показ текста, который её остановит
}

function soundStop() {
  audio.pause();
  fun.style.display = "block";
  sad.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<button id="fun" onclick="soundStart()">Включение мелодии</button>
<button id="sad" onclick="soundStop()">Выключение мелодии</button>
```

Comment: переменная audio должна быть снаружи функции чтобы обе функции и запуска и остановки могли видеть объект связанный с ней. Функции не нужно вкладывать друг в друга

Comment: Большое спасибо! Помогло.